# Redmine не работают вкладки Задачи, Календарь и др

Tags: centos, redmine

Centos 7 + Redmine 3.1.1 на Ruby 2.2 Rails 4.2.4 + nginx 1.8 + unicorn. 
На домашнюю страницу заходит, всё без проблем. При попытке перейти в Задачи или любую другую вкладку:

> Internal error
>   An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
>   If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance.
>   If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error.

В production.log вот что получается:

> Started GET "/projects/redmine/issues/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-19 17:56:29 +0300
>   Processing by IssuesController#new as HTML
>     Parameters: {"project_id"=>"redmine"}
>     Current user: admin (id=1)
>     Rendered issues/_form_custom_fields.html.erb (2.8ms)
>     Rendered issues/_attributes.html.erb (13.5ms)
>     Rendered issues/_form.html.erb (20.1ms)
>     Rendered attachments/_form.html.erb (1.9ms)
>     Rendered issues/new.html.erb within layouts/base (23.1ms)
>   Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 45ms (ActiveRecord: 9.8ms)
>
> ActionView::Template::Error ([bug] frozen object  (JSON::Ext::Generator::State) allocated):
>       11: <% end %>
>       12: 
>       13: 
>       14: <%= file_field_tag 'attachments[dummy][file]',
>       15:       :id => nil,
>       16:       :class => 'file_selector',
>       17:       :multiple => true,
>     app/views/attachments/_form.html.erb:14:in   `_app_views_attachments__form_html_erb__3514053648094117852_93197800'
>
>     app/views/issues/new.html.erb:33:in`block in  _app_views_issues_new_html_erb___3060175743672650348_84590520'
>     app/helpers/application_helper.rb:1027:in `labelled_form_for'
>
>     app/views/issues/new.html.erb:5:in`_app_views_issues_new_html_erb___3060175743672650348_84590520'
>     app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:130:in `block (2 levels) in new'
>
>     app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:129:in`new'
>     lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:63:in `sudo_mode'

Сталкивался кто-нить с подобным?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

У вас очень странные названия файлов.
поидее вместо
`_app_views_attachments__form_html_erb__3514053648094117852_93197800`
`_app_views_issues_new_html_erb___3060175743672650348_84590520`

должно бы быть:

`app_views_attachments__form_html.erb`
`app_views_issues_new_html.erb`

Посмотрите свои конфиги.

Comment: Это скомпилированные ассеты, насколько понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же проблема -- я сделал следующее для ее разрешения:

1. Переименовал папку "vendor" в "vendorx"
2. Выполнил команду `bundle`

Вот так:

```
mv vendor vendorx
bundle install
```

После этого все вернулось к нормальной работе, и когда я понял, что все в порядке, я удалил папку "vendorx"

Comment: Hi, Lorin. This part of StackOverflow community is russian-speaking, so i've translated your answer as close to original text as i could.